# Symfony command line on Ubuntu without using PHP

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu

Why if we type a Symfony command line on Ubuntu without using PHP, we don't have an error ?

For example

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

is the same thing than :

```
app/console cache:clear
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't have an error.

```
app/console cache:clear
[OK] Cache for the "dev" environment (debug=true) was successfully cleared.
```

Because php env defined in app/console

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

Also, app/console should have permissions for execute